# Is there any computer parts that can be trashed safely (for the environment)?

Tags: power-supply, compact-disc

I have some (non working) computer parts that I want to get rid of.

I'm pretty sure most of computer hardware can't be put in the trash safely but I want to know if some of them can.

(At the moment I have a CD-ROM and a power supply that I want to get rid of)

Comment: Most computer parts has electric circuits, which usually contain lead. This applies to all electronic equipment, not just computer parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cite [petersohn](https://superuser.com/users/32095/petersohn) comment:

> Most computer parts has electric
>   circuits, which usually contain lead.
>   This applies to all electronic
>   equipment, not just computer parts.

Since [lead is poison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_poisoning), we can safely assume that we can't trash 99.9% of computer parts.

As others pointed out, it's wiser to donate them (if in working order) to charities or any people who will use them.

Most cities (at least in North America) have recycling centers where you can safely dispose of these "dangerous" things.

Answer (score 3):

It is best to drop them off at a local recycler, or donate them to Goodwill or other charity, they will test them, if they are good they will be sold, if not they will recycle them for you.

Comment: There are also charities that will accept donations of old computers/parts, refurbish them, and then provide computers for underprivileged children and schools.

Answer (score 3):

Our town has a recycling center specifically for electronics. You'd need to ask place like that. Also, different recycling centers may give you different answers.

Answer (score 0):

Best Buy will take almost all electronics and recycle them free.  Exceptions are large CRTs since they have to do something special with them.  For those items they charge you $10 or so and then give you a $10 rebate card.  Good option if you happen to live near one of their stores.